# Resque Job can't connect to localhost to POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, resque

My Resque Job can't connect to localhost to POST request...

When I try `UserCreatorJob.perform_now(options)` it runs ok.

When I use `UserCreatorJob.perform_later(options)` it goes to the resque queue and than, when performing, it fails with `Connection refused - connect(2) for "fe80::1%lo0" port 3000`

`user_creator_job.rb`

```
class UserCreatorJob < Jobs::ApplicationJob
  queue_as :user

  def perform(*args)
    conn :post, 'api/v1/users', args
  end

  def conn
    Faraday.new(url: 'http://localhost:3000') do |faraday|
      faraday.request :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
      faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
      faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
      faraday.token_auth('')
    end
  end
end
```

If I perform the post with CURL everything goes as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think resque may not like posting to localhost.

Try adding this line to your /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 my.api.dev
```

Then, in your code, replace http://localhost:3000 with http://my.api.dev:3000

Comment: Thanks for the tip, as soon as I can test it I will reply!